# C# .NET MAUI IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, ip, maui

I'm net to C# and .NET MAUI so this may be something I don't understand or it may be a bug in .NET MAUI.

I have this code:

```cs
//byte[] ipPorts = pcapngReader.ReadBytes(4);
ushort udpSourcePort = (ushort)IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(pcapngReader.ReadUInt16());
pcapngUDPPacketPosition += sizeof(ushort);
ushort udpDestinationPort = (ushort)IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder((ushort)pcapngReader.ReadUInt16());
pcapngUDPPacketPosition += sizeof(ushort);
ushort udpPacketLength = pcapngReader.ReadUInt16();
ushort udpPatketLengthHostOrder = (ushort)IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(udpPacketLength);
pcapngUDPPacketPosition += sizeof(Int16);
ushort udpPacketChecksum = (ushort)IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder((ushort)pcapngReader.ReadUInt16());
pcapngUDPPacketPosition += sizeof(Int16);
```

When I'm debugging listed below is what I get in the debug window:

```
pcapngUDPPacketPosition 74  int
udpSourcePort           0   ushort
udpDestinationPort  0   ushort
udpPacketLength         9217
udpPatketLengthHost 0   ushort
udpPacketChecksum   0   ushort
```

This data is being read in from a pcapng file and I've checked with hexinator and both the udpSourcePort and udsDestinationPort contain the hex value 0x1381 (4993 decimal).  The udpPacketLength field contains 0x0124 (292 decimal) which is the packet length that Wireshark is showing.  When I do IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder on 9217 the function returns "0" which makes no sense at all to this newbe.  I've tried a number of examples that Google has presented and none of them have worked.

Thanks in advance for your help.

I've tried the above code and was expecting non zero results after the IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder function was executed.

Comment: What is pcapngReader?  Please show the source data in hex and what results you expect from each line (in hex)

Comment: pcapgReader is created here: 

 await using var pcapngStream = File.Open(pcapngFileNameTextbox.Text, FileMode.Open);
 using var pcapngReader = new BinaryReader(pcapngStream, Encoding.UTF8, false);

Hex dump:
507B9DB700B5001C2D051266080045000138000040004011BBC9C0A8FE84C0A8FE151381138101248951

The "13811381" on the second row are the UDP source and destination port numbers which I expect to end up as 4993 decimal. As mentioned above I expect the length to be 292 and not 9217. I know the issue is endianness, however I just can't seem to get IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder() to work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include additional code, properly formatted.  Code stuffed in comments is very difficult to read.  My first guess would be that ReadUint16 is not respecting the byte order.

Comment: from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader.readuint16?view=net-7.0) "Reads a 2-byte unsigned integer from the current stream using **little-endian** encoding and advances the position of the stream by two bytes."

Comment: you should probably use `ReadBytes` instead